# How can I heal myself as a Skeleton Barbarian?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, pathfinder-society, negative-energy

Skeletons have negative healing, which can cause problems. Only very few spells can provide healing during encounters.
Especially in Pathfinder Society, where each time you play with different people, so you cannot be sure someone can cast Harm or Sooth on you. As a Barbarian, it is very hard to cast spells.

(Healing in exploration mode is covered by Stitch Flesh + Assurance (Medicine) and a Pearly White Aeon Stone).

[Battle Medicine](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=760) would work, but the main reason I picked Skeleton is the [Well-Armed](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3537) feat, which doesn't leave an empty hand.

Potions take two actions (1 to retrieve, 1 to consume), and are rather small amounts. Also, they need free a hand.

Are there any other, better options?

Comment: First off, Healers Gloves don’t work - the item explicitly calls out the effect as being **Positive**. Just because you can’t _harm_ undead with it, doesn’t mean you can _heal_ them with it. (This is also why you can’t heal undead with literally any spell that does Negative/Void damage. The spell needs to explicitly call out that it does healing to heal a target.)

Comment: You are right, I just checked the traits. Edited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Fast Healing

The best option to heal with those restrictions would be to gain either fast healing or regeneration, though the options for achieving this are limited:

- [Gathering Moss](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=4180) (10th + [Stalwart Defender](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=205) 2nd): fast healing = level, once per day for one minute
- [Mantle of Heaven's Slopes](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=1222) (6th rank divine spell, 16th level and several archetype feats for one slot) fast healing 2 for one minute, could cast before an encounter
- [Crimson Shroud](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=898) (6th + [Red Mantis Assassin](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=17) 2nd): fast healing = 1/2 level, several times per day for one minute as an action
- [Grand Medic's Mask](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3435) (20th + [Wizard](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=742) or [Druid](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=701) 2nd): fast healing 5
- [Immortal Bear](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=200) (20th + [Ursine Avenger Hood](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=200) 2nd): fast healing 5 in Ursine Avenger Form

[*Regeneration*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=248) has the positive trait and wouldn't work for a skeleton, and these options for fast healing are either inaccessible in Pathfinder Society play or otherwise quite limited.

### Temporary Hit Points

Without an open hand, relying on your allies, or any of the above options, you could instead take any of several abilities which expand  a barbarian's ability to gain temporary Hit Points through their rage:

- [Renewed Vigor](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=153) (8th): 1/2 level + Constitution mod temporary HP as an action
- [Come and Get Me](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=157) (10th): 1-2x Constitution mod temporary HP after hitting a creature that just hit you
- [Siphon Life](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3755) (10th, aftermath Barbarian feat): temporary HP based on void damage dealt alongside an unarmed Strike

Or if you're willing to take an archetype, have a skill feat, or have an [Adopted Ancestry](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=751) (such as through the [As in Life, So in Death](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3532) skeleton feat), then there are additional options that could be considered:

- [Stalwart Defender Dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=4172) (2nd): 1/2 level temporary HP, once per minute
- [Living Vessel Dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3815) (2nd): level + Strength mod temporary HP when brought to 0 HP as a reaction
- [Sacred Defense](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1183) (7th skill feat, master in Religion): 5-25 temporary HP, up to once per minute
- [Show-Off](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=4144) (8th + [Acrobat](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=45) 2nd): up to 2x level temporary HP on successful "meaningful" Acrobatics or Athletics check
- [Drain Emotion](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=4047) (9th + 5th): level temporary HP after counteracting adjacent emotion effect, once per day
- [Invigorating Breath](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=4110) (10h + [Scion of Domora](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=202) 4th + [Familiar Master](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1970) 2nd): 20-30 temporary HP, once per hour
- [Drain Vitality](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3231) (10th + [Beast Gunner](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=116) 6th): level temporary HP as an action, once per minute
- [Death's Door](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1142) (14th + [Swordmaster](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=33) 6th): 2x level temporary HP as a reaction when brought to 0 HP, once per 10 minutes
- [Keep up the Good Fight](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3586) (14th + [Knight Vigilant](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=27) 6th) level temporary HP as a reaction when brought to 0 HP, increases wounded value by 1
- [Worm Form](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=4368) (14th + [Worm Caller](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=208) 2nd): 40 temporary HP as a big worm for 2 actions
- [Vivacious Bravado](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1542) (16th + 4th + [Swashbuckler](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=43) 2nd): level + Charisma mod temporary HP as an action after gaining panache this turn
- [Replenishment of War](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=293) (20th + 4th + [Cleric](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=5) 2nd): up to level temporary HP on damaging creature
- Dwarf

  - [Avenge in Glory](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=964) (1st): level temporary HP as a reaction when a nearby ally becomes dying
- Orc

  - [Victorious Vigor](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=88) (5th): Constitution mod temporary HP as a reaction when reducing a creature to 0 HP
  - [Undying Ferocity](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1291) (9th + 1st): level temporary HP as a reaction when brought to 0, once per day (more frequently with another feat)
  - [Spell Devourer](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1293) (13th + 9th + 1st): automatic temporary HP on successful saves against magic

Many of these options are limited or restricted in PFS play, but some are standardly available if you don't have access for your character (such as from a [boon or charity reward](https://2e.aonprd.com/PFS.aspx)).

Comment: Red Mantis Assassin is not allowed in PFS

Comment: And at least some of these are Uncommon/Rare, and should be indicated as such since they might have limited (or even no) access in PFS.